# Adding a Stylesheet with the HAP

Tags: c#, .net, html, css, html-agility-pack

I have a stylesheet stored as a string which I'm trying to add to a parsed HtmlDocument using the Html Agility Pack. I can't set the InnerText of a `style` node because it has no setter. What's the best way of doing this?

Comment: Did you try adding a whole style node?

Comment: `new HtmlNode(...)` and append it? Not sure it will work, but worth a shot.

Comment: But the `InnerText` property has no setter so I can't set the content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Untested, but should give you the idea:

```
// doc is the HtmlDocument
var style = doc.CreateElement("style");
var text = doc.CreateTextNode("some CSS here");
style.AppendChild(text);
doc.DocumentNode.AppendChild(style); // or, AppendChild to any node
```